# C# - Continue program flow on button press

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a little dialog game in c# winforms and would need that the program flow is paused until the user presses a button.
At the moment this is the code for generating the label:

```
Label displayText;
public void createDisplayText ( string message, bool continueOnButton = true )
{
    displayText = new Label()
        {
            Location = new Point(300, 30),
            Font = new Font("Consolas", 11F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0))),
            ForeColor = Color.White,
            BackColor = Color.Black,
            Size = new Size(img.Width - 70, img.Height - 50),
            Text = message
        };
    if ( continueOnButton )
        textKeyPress = true;
    Controls.Add(displayText);
}
public void hideDisplayText ()
{
    if ( displayText != null )
        displayText.Dispose();
}
```

And inside the Form_KeyDown method I entered the following:

```
if (textKeyPress)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
           hideDisplayBox();
    }
```

**Question:**
How do I enter this in a program code, so the program waits for the Text to be hidden and *then* resumes.
The call (if possible) should not be more complicated than

```
createDisplayText ( "Some sort of message" );
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: You you shouldn't *really* pause the program itself in WinForms as this is blocking everything.

Comment: Do you need a "Thread" instead??

Comment: @Robert Yes, but if I dont do this there will be no delay between texts and the user wouldnt be able to read it.

Comment: @Ian: You should probably dig into the basics of UI programming with WinForms, especially timers, events, threads and properties. Buzzwords here are *non-blocking UI*, e.g.

Answer (score 2):

Use a different thread for UI and program flow. When what you want is needed, put the program flow thread to sleep and then wake it using a call from UI after the message is hidden or just give it a timer.